# Is there a way to get Safari extensions to work in a standalone or fullscreen PWA?

Tags: ios, progressive-web-apps, safari-extension

In my experience if I add a website with a PWA manifest indicating fullscreen/standalone display mode, Safari extensions are disabled.

Is there any way to get fullscreen + extensions in Safari for iOS/iPadOS?